# How do I get DVD menus in mplayer

Tags: video, dvd, mplayer

I love mplayer, but I can't figure out how to get the DVD menus working. I heard you need to type something like this:

`mplayer dvdnav://`

but I don't know what comes after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your mplayer has dvdnav support it's -

`mplayer dvdnav:// -dvd-device /dev/XXX`

Where typically now XXX is sr0 or in some cases sr1

Comment: No clue what Bednar is but if the command works then mplayer has dvdnav support. I keep some recent builds here for users though do Not provide mencoder & likely never will - https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mplayer-test I'm probably going to switch the default dvd device from the current /dev/dvd to /dev/sr0 in future builds so many won't need to specify the device.

Comment: Sorry Bednar is what auto correct thinks dvdnav is.